# postgresql send variables to a function, casting?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

In one place I have

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateGeo2(text, float4, float4) RETURNS float AS $$
```

followed later by

```
SELECT updateGeo2('area', 40.88, -90.56);
```

and I get

```
error : ERROR:  function updategeo2(unknown, numeric, numeric) does not exist
```

so it doesn't know that I tried to pass in a text variable, followed by a float variable and another float variable, it sees these as "unknown, numeric and numeric", lame. How do I let it know the types I am passing in?

Comment: try this way: SELECT updateGeo2('area', (40.88)::float4, (-90.56)::float4);

Comment: @sufleR thanks , this worked, I also set `area` as ::text , you can write that as an answer if you want some points

Comment: What does `SELECT version()` tell you about the version you run? I tested with 8.4.15 and it works as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
SELECT updateGeo2('area', (40.88)::float4, (-90.56)::float4);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Clarify misunderstanding

First of all, this should **work as is**, without type cast. I tested with PostgreSQL 9.1, 9.2 and also with **8.4.15**. You must be running an earlier point-release or there is some other misunderstanding (like wrong `search_path`). Your information is *misleading*.

Except for ad-hoc calls, you should always add explicit type casts anyway to disambiguate. PostgreSQL allows [*function overloading*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html). If another function should be created with the signature:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateGeo2(text, numeric, numeric) RETURNS text AS $$ ..
```

... then it would take precedence over the other one due to the default type `numeric` for numeric literals. Existing code might break.

If, on the other hand, you add a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateGeo2(char(5), numeric, numeric) RETURNS text AS $$ ..
```

Then Postgres does not know what to do any more and throws an exception:

> ERROR:  function updategeo2(unknown, numeric, numeric) is not unique

#### Proper syntax

```
SELECT updateGeo2('area', '40.88'::float4, '-90.56'::float4);
```

Or, more verbose in standard SQL:

```
SELECT updateGeo2('area', cast('40.88' AS float4), cast('-90.56' AS float4));
```

Or, if you really wanted to avoid single quotes (and colons):

```
SELECT updateGeo2('area', float4 '40.88', float4 '-90.56');
```

This way you cast a *numeric literal* to data type [`float4`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) (= [`real`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html)) directly.
More about [type casting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) in the manual.

`(40.88)::float4` works, too, but subtly less effective. First, `40.88` is taken to be of type `numeric` (the default type for this numeric literal containing a dot). Then the value is cast to `float4`. Makes two type casts.

More about [numeric constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) in the manual.

Comment: thanks, do you have knowledge for this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770869/postgresql-pgplsql-increment-float-in-loop

Comment: @CQM: I added more after running some tests.