# Incrementing a number in a loop in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, increment, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I couldn't find this immediately from the examples. I want to increment a variable in a loop, in a function.

For instance:

```
DECLARE
   iterator float4;
BEGIN
   iterator = 1;

    while iterator < 999
       .....
      iterator ++;
END;
```

How would this be done?

I was looking at this document about flow control:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

And none of them seem to be relevant for me, unless these are absolutely the only ways to simulate incrementing a variable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To increment a variable in plpgsql:

```
iterator := iterator + 1;
```

There is no `++` operator.

About the assignment operator in plpgsql:

- [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace/7641260#7641260)

Correct [syntax for loops in PL/pgSQL in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Your code fragment would work like this:

```
DECLARE
   iterator float4 := 1;  -- we can init at declaration time
BEGIN
   WHILE iterator < 999
   LOOP
      iterator := iterator + 1;
      -- do stuff
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Simpler, faster alternative with a [`FOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) loop:

```
   FOR i in 1 .. 999   -- i is integer automatically, not float4
   LOOP
      -- do stuff
   END LOOP;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR)

> The variable `name` is automatically defined as type `integer` and exists only inside the loop (any existing definition of the variable name is ignored within the loop).

Comment: within my loop I am doing sql queries, those statements use `=` correct, ie `UPDATE mytable SET this_id = finalid...`

Comment: @CQM: Correct, those are embedded SQL statements, where `=` is the assignement operator. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace).

Answer (score 5):

For a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0 ; 
BEGIN
   WHILE counter <= 5 LOOP
      counter := counter + 1 ; 
      RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
   END LOOP ; 
END; $$
```

if you want to avoid declare variable (more concise)

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   FOR counter IN 1..5 LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
   END LOOP;
END; $$
```

[credits](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/)